# java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 66 but was expecting 64

Tags: java, security, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

This is how I am generating a key pair:

```
private void generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
//        kpg.initialize(1024);
kpg.initialize(512);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

System.out.println("Generated Key Pair");
dumpKeyPair(kp);
}
```

Following creates token and token signature:

```
public String makeTokenSignature(String message) throws GeneralSecurityException {
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signature.initSign(getPrivateKey());
signature.update(message.getBytes());

byte[] signatureValue = signature.sign();
return encodeBASE64(signatureValue);
}

public String createTokenString(String userName) {
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
String tokenString = userName + "some other values..";

return tokenString;
}
```

Here's the validator code:

```
public boolean isValidTokenSignature(String message, byte[] signatureValue) throws     GeneralSecurityException {
Signature signature2 = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signature2.initVerify(getPublicKey());
signature2.update(message.getBytes());
return signature2.verify(signatureValue);
}
```

Problem I see:
When userName.length >= 16 && userName < 18, validation code works fine. Can someone tell me how does key size affects the permissible length of userName?
When I was using kpg.initialize(1024) in GenerateKeyPair code lower limit for username was 18 chars.

Comment: I don't see any link between the userName and the signature generation/verification code. Maybe you should clear that up first.

Comment: At least the first two questions you asked seem to have been answered correctly. You should accept answers, or indicate why the given answers are not suitable.